# How I can convert date and time into number value on app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function myFunction() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var maintenanceSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var startTimeCell = maintenanceSheet.getRange(3, 6);
  var endTimeCell = maintenanceSheet.getRange(3, 11);
  var durationCell = maintenanceSheet.getRange(3, 13);
  durationCell = (endTimeCell - startTimeCell) * 24;
  maintenanceSheet.getRange(3, 13).setValue(durationCell);
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from `How I can convert date and time into number value on app script?` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: you don't need for app script, with googlesheet you can use VALUE() formula to convert date to number

Answer (score 0):

#### Difference in days

```
function myFunction() {
  var day = 86400000;
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var maintenanceSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var startTimeCell = new Date(maintenanceSheet.getRange(3, 6)).valueOf();
  var endTimeCell = new Date(maintenanceSheet.getRange(3, 11)).valueOf();
  const d = Math.abs(endTimeCell - startTimeCell);
  var days = Math.floor(d / day);
  maintenanceSheet.getRange(3, 13).setValue(days);
}
```